# How to make a case statement and ignore a user's input postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

So I have a WebApp that allows the user to input parameters in a query to obtain results using the expression for example country

```
:Country   -- varchar type
:Grade     -- int
```

I have a query where I check against the students grade if the users decides to enter a parameter or not.

### Query 1

```
select count(distinct s.students),s.gradenumber
from student s
join blablabla
where (Case when length(:Grade)>0 
            then gradenumber = :Grade 
            else gradenumber between 1 and 12
       END)
```

Since I know a school grade has a limt between 1-12 I can solve this problem in such a way

### Problem

The problem with the paramter(:Country) is if its left empty then the query wont work. So I write a case statement to ignore the user's input if its empty and to carry on with the query

In the where statement below I check against a users input of a country name

```
 SELECT l.longtext as language,count(distinct s.studentnr) as Studentcount

        FROM student s
            join pupil p on p.id = s.pupilid
            join pupillanguage pl on pl.personid = p.id
            join language l on l.id = pl.languageid
            join pupilnationality pn on pn.personid = p.id
            join country ctf on ctf.id = pn.countryid

         where (CASE when LENGTH(:Land)<3    <----- focus on the where statement
                     then ctf.text = :Land 
                     else ctf.text like '%'
                 END)
```

This where statement is giving me 0 results 
Should i be using coalesce?

```
where (CASE when LENGTH(:Land)<3   
                     then ctf.text = :Land 
                     else ctf.text like ....
                 END)
```

Comment: It's generally much better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: what about left join with country??

Comment: how would you express it then? I usually use it most of the time!@jarlh

Comment: left join country will change my results how? @ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem is

```
 (CASE WHEN LENGTH(:Land)>3 then ctf.text = :Land else ctf.text like '%%' end)
```

I left one wild card character out %%

If you happen to know any alternatives to this statement please add!

Answer (score 1):

what about  OR instead case in where

```
 where   ctf.text = :Land or ctf.text like '%countryname%'
```

Comment: this is not what im looking for

Comment: focus on the where statement, the joins has nothing to do with my problem

Comment: can explain a bit more

Comment: you partially help me answer by the two wildcards you placed

Answer (score 0):

I would advise:

```
where ctf.text = :Land or :Land is null
```

However, your logic is also checking the length.  So:

```
where ( (ctf.text = :Land and length(:Land) < 3) or :Land is null or length(:Land) >= 3)
```

Comment: got 0 results, sry